# Draw a heart in ASCII-art style based on user input

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, ascii, ascii-art

I have a problem that I hope you can help with.

The Java program should print hearts in ASCII-art style, based on the input `N` given by a user.

**Information:**

- Characters to print: ♡ ♥
- The printing of the *top* and *bottom* part of the heart can be done separately.
- The solution must be based on for-loops.
- `N` determines the top part of the heart:

  1. *The slanted outer sides at the top have `N` hearts in them.*
  2. *The flat parts at the top have `N` hearts in them.*
  3. *The gap between the two flat parts is `N` hearts wide.*

**Examples:**

- [N = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fICix.png)
- [N = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKm5.png)
- [N = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zIEP.png)
- [N = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkiUf.png)

**My current code:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of hearts you want to print");
    int userInput = scan.nextInt();

    printTop(userInput);
}
```

```java
public static void printTop(int userInput) {
    String row = "";
    int width = 2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput;
    for (int height = 0; height < userInput; height++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput - 1; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♥";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♥";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput - 1; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        row += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

**Thoughts:**

- The first line of the heart is based on:

  ```
  2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput
  ```
- The *colored hearts* must increase by 2 for each line.
- The *center hearts* must be reduced by 2 for each line.
- The *transparent hearts* on the side must be reduced by 1 for each line.

**Questions:**

- How can I get the different types of hearts to do their "job" on each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the task with the following code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChristmasHearts {
    private int userInput;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    String topHeart = "";
    String middleHeart = "";
    String bottomHeart = "";

    public ChristmasHearts(int input) {
        this.userInput = input;
    }

    public void draw() {
        calcWidthAndHeight(this.userInput);
        drawTopOfHeart();
        drawBottomOfHeart();
    }

    private void drawTopOfHeart() {
        int whites = 0;
        int blacks = 1;
        int center = 1;
        int heightOfTopHeart = 1;
        int isEvenCenterLessSubtractor = 2;
        int isNotEvenCenterLessSubtractor = 1;

        if (this.userInput == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < heightOfTopHeart; i++) {
                this.topHeart += "♥";
                this.topHeart += "♡";
                this.topHeart += "♥";
            }
            System.out.println(topHeart);
        } else {
            whites = this.userInput - 1;
            blacks = this.userInput;
            center = this.userInput;
            heightOfTopHeart = this.userInput - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < heightOfTopHeart; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < whites; j++) {
                    this.topHeart += "♡";
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < blacks; j++) {
                    this.topHeart += "♥";
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < center; j++) {
                    this.topHeart += "♡";
                }

                if (this.userInput >= 5 && center <= 0) {
                    if (isEven(this.userInput) && center == 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < blacks; j++) {
                            this.topHeart += "♥";
                        }
                    } else if (isEven(this.userInput) && center < 0) {
                        int rightSideBlacks = blacks - isEvenCenterLessSubtractor;

                        for (int j = 0; j < rightSideBlacks; j++) {
                            this.topHeart += "♥";
                        }
                        isEvenCenterLessSubtractor += 2;
                    } else if (!isEven(this.userInput) && center < 0) {
                        int rightSideBlacks = blacks - isNotEvenCenterLessSubtractor;

                        for (int j = 0; j < rightSideBlacks; j++) {
                            this.topHeart += "♥";
                        }
                        isNotEvenCenterLessSubtractor += 2;
                    } else {
                        int factorToSubtract = 2;
                        int rightSideBlacks = blacks - factorToSubtract;

                        for (int j = 0; j < rightSideBlacks; j++) {
                            this.topHeart += "♥";
                        }
                        factorToSubtract += 2;
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int j = 0; j < blacks; j++) {
                        this.topHeart += "♥";
                    }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < whites; j++) {
                    this.topHeart += "♡";
                }

                whites -= 1;
                blacks += 2;
                center -= 2;

                if (this.userInput == 0) {
                    this.topHeart = "";
                }
                System.out.println(topHeart);
                topHeart = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawMiddelOfHeart() {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
            this.middleHeart += "♥";
        }

        if (this.userInput == 0) {
            this.middleHeart = "";
        }

        System.out.println(this.middleHeart);
        middleHeart = "";
    }

    private void drawBottomOfHeart() {
        int whites = 1;
        int blacks = 1;
        int heightOfBottomHeart = 1;

        if (this.userInput == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < heightOfBottomHeart; i++) {
                this.bottomHeart += "♡";
                this.bottomHeart += "♥";
                this.bottomHeart += "♡";
            }
            System.out.println(bottomHeart);

        } else {
            heightOfBottomHeart = this.height - this.userInput;
            whites = 1;
            blacks = this.width - 2;

            drawMiddelOfHeart();
            for (int i = 0; i < heightOfBottomHeart; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < whites; j++) {
                    this.bottomHeart += "♡";
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < blacks; j++) {
                    this.bottomHeart += "♥";
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < whites; j++) {
                    this.bottomHeart += "♡";
                }

                blacks -= 2;
                whites += 1;

                if (this.userInput == 0) {
                    this.bottomHeart = "";
                }
                System.out.println(bottomHeart);
                bottomHeart = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isEven(int n) {
        return n % 2 == 0;
    }

    private void calcWidthAndHeight(int n) {
        this.width = 3;
        this.height = 2;

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= (n - 1); counter++) {
            this.width += 5;

            if (isEven(counter)) {
                this.height += 4;
            } else {
                this.height += 3;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        scanner.close();

        ChristmasHearts heart = new ChristmasHearts(input);
        heart.draw();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Draw an ASCII-art heart, filled and empty

Imagine a *coordinate plane* and draw a figure that consists of two half-сircles and one half-rhombus.

[image: two half-сircles and one half-rhombus]

Pictures 1 and 2:

[image: ASCII-art heart filled] [image: ASCII-art heart empty]

Figure 1 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxbsIwEIb3PMUvBmQnclR16JLSN2BirDoYCNQ0OCE2yFbhQTp26Iv1RVLbBJQ0ouoNd9bd/3/2yRt@4KyscrlZvjVNtZ8XYoFFwZXClAuJ9wgu2r7SXLtyKMUSWzclM10LuX5@Aa/XirZiH0JqSEzwkF1bq7IG8X3r@kxmrj5OcI8Y/pwkXXtPb7y@1ZmOxzhPzxEuXoGQQL7DeDwYX4J4MnUr6tdU7WpNiEkkjUNGAhtb6hnyJuASxyOGKBZQrI@iNPoLYvEUnnwG8bkihl6XBYO94Z9ZpfNtWu51WrnP0GT0/fGFEc0G6rxQ@b8RnwPEb1UhSUdxis751DQ/)

```java
int n = 6;
for (int y = -n; y <= 2 * n; y++) {
    for (int x = -2 * n; x <= 2 * n; x++)
        if ((y <= 0 &&
                ((int) Math.sqrt((x+n)*(x+n) + y*y) <= n
                        || (int) Math.sqrt((x-n)*(x-n) + y*y) <= n))
                || (y > 0 && Math.abs(x) <= 2 * n - y))
            System.out.print("♥ ");
        else
            System.out.print("♡ ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output 1:

```
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ 
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ 
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ 
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ 
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ 
♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
```

---

Figure 2 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxTsMwEIb3PMWvDpWdyBFiYAnhDZg6Iga3TYvb1AmxW9mifRBGBl6MFwm2m6KEqIgb7qy7///skzf8wFlVF3Kz3LZtvZ@XYoFFyZXCIxcSbxFcdH2luXblUIkldm5KZroRcv30DN6sFe3EPoTUkMhxl/20VlUD4vvW9ZnMXL3PcYsY/pwkfftAb7y@05mexzjPwBEuXoGQQL7BdDoaX4J4MnUr6pdUvTaaEJNIGoeMBDa2FHkOeRVwieMRYxQLKDZEURr9BbF4CE8@g/hcERN8YVkw2Cv@mVW62KXVXqe1@wxNJl/vn5jQbKQuSlX8G/ExQvxWlZL0FKfonE9t@w0)

```java
int n = 6;
for (int y = -n; y <= 2 * n; y++) {
    for (int x = -2 * n; x <= 2 * n; x++)
        if ((y <= 0 &&
                ((int) Math.sqrt((x+n)*(x+n) + y*y) == n
                        || (int) Math.sqrt((x-n)*(x-n) + y*y) == n))
                || (y > 0 && Math.abs(x) == 2 * n - y))
            System.out.print("♥ ");
        else
            System.out.print("♡ ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output 2:

```
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ 
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ 
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ 
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ 
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ 
♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ 
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Print out an ASCII circle and axes with characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66844335/16314724)

• [How to draw a double empty ASCII rhombus?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155637/16314724)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Nice challenge:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A {
    public static final char COLORED = '♥';
    public static final char WHITE = '♡';

    public static void printTop(int userInput) {
        StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer();

        int width = 2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput;

        // white hearts at the outside
        int outerHearts = userInput - 1;
        // left colored section or complete
        // colored line from the widest point
        int heartsSection1 = userInput;
        // right color section or 0 from the widest point
        int heartsSection2 = userInput;
        // white hearts between 2 colored sections
        int innerHearts = userInput;

        boolean upperPart = true;
        while (heartsSection1 > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < outerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heartsSection1; i++) {
                row.append(COLORED);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < innerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < heartsSection2; i++) {
                row.append(COLORED);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < outerHearts; i++) {
                row.append(WHITE);
            }
            row.append("\n");
            if (upperPart) {
                if (outerHearts > 0) {
                    outerHearts--;
                    innerHearts = Math.max(0, innerHearts - 2);
                    if (outerHearts == 0) {
                        heartsSection1 = width;
                        heartsSection2 = 0;
                    } else {
                        heartsSection1 += 2;
                        heartsSection2 += 2;
                    }
                } else {
                    // line with only colored hearts,
                    // from now on the hearts reduce
                    upperPart = false;
                }
            }
            if (!upperPart) {
                outerHearts++;
                heartsSection1 -= 2;
            }
            if (heartsSection1 <= 0)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(row.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of hearts you want to print");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();

        printTop(userInput);
    }
}
```

In my output it is not a perfect rectangle as the white heart is a little smaller than the colored heart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `java.awt` package to draw these characters `♥♡` as a black and white picture:

[image: picture]

And then you can print a 2D array of pixels as characters that make up this picture:

```
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                 ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡ ♡ ♡           
      ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡     ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡         ♡     ♡       ♡         
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡   ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡           ♡           ♡   ♡           ♡       
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡             ♡ ♡             ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡             ♡               ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡                             ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡                           ♡     
      ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡                         ♡       
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                 ♡                     ♡         
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                     ♡                 ♡           
          ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                       ♡                 ♡           
            ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                         ♡             ♡             
              ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                             ♡         ♡               
                ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                                 ♡     ♡                 
                  ♡ ♡                                   ♡   ♡                   
                  ♡                                       ♡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTNctowEL7zFFufbHBEwrGUtqFNMsy0SYZwyTBMR9iyETG2R5KDM508SI459MXyInQly8SG6KCf/dPq20@7po/0JMtZug4fdju@yTOhYI1CQreKdIedQ1GUpYpc4jRlacjED9yxUh3b8Q2NGRkXUcQECyf6NOx08mKZ8ACChEoJvylP4W8HcFi5VFTh8pjxEDaode@U4Gk8XwAVsfSssR48VfMFyleMCiVhhK7acpbd8pIl0nXeXv69vbw6PqRsCzpfV0/k7mI6ufSNgNz@Op9c@zAYeD6cesN97H4fskLlhdpLokyAa64EkW3hs722mZAeVbbjgieIDMglpqVvb4ndxkXN0MAxLAb3Wlo95JLQHCsUuhw@jeAUvgG@7hUcdHAAnIOAPAIXXThWp7yJNBCvjgdf4eTsOPTdk1RsQ/C1JMccVZKiayPec6eazdLvditFF77nVNCNxhxkVoiAWfhBZRAKuj2wi8w78Y2oFoY2oElzYJWHyAMahjoOlUAhFyygheJZ6mO9YZNJBQGVTMLp3lUwVYgU1IrB4CeyRNAnyCLIDQtQTBUS6YFBkeOBS5unde@b1ZKuZtQBkariaWnFGoh0MgqzbVb/6ENAoEpb/iOdG5GYqZmgqcTqb1ykX0QTyezSwH/KAkXTOGGwzIo01Dw3vpZRRuaa1PA6T2usrBFDJ7vloVqhcxWFVMeeRrwLg7bpivF4pd5t7fnYuPW1wXx3GB0xTAPQsnTN5b69x28ryez@9uLP@H6G0@T6fHrfeMeVoPmKBxLLHNstZum@i70qCY1CLWziUDsRyZTpB9FHSs3eCt0KV3x1r4aiNMeT@vjUahkm/8kN2QqumGsy8cHJ07huQTxhroMxiZZ57QIZ4uVBzRgtqfBZzA1ci2Hng36BvWCIyxeLJe57Pe/j5rKujNdobALi9tC27h17EKdXY3eNZPdghM7lpR3HXqaBB@WcL@brBV509p6t/Z6oHdpW8rzb/Qc)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] hearts = stringToPixels("♥♡", new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 22), 0);
  // output
  for (int[] row : hearts) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i : row)
      sb.append(i != 0 ? "♡ " : "  ");
    if (sb.indexOf("♡") > -1)
      System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param str source string to draw
 * @param f   font to render text
 * @param pd  padding as a precaution, in most cases 0
 * @return the 2D array of pixels that make up this string
 */
static int[][] stringToPixels(String str, Font f, int pd) {
  FontRenderContext ctx = new FontRenderContext(f.getTransform(), false, false);
  Rectangle bounds = f.getStringBounds(str, ctx).getBounds();
  int width = bounds.width + pd * 2;
  int height = bounds.height + pd * 2;
  BufferedImage image =
          new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
  Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
  graphics.setFont(f);
  graphics.drawString(str, pd + bounds.x, pd - bounds.y);
  //ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("str.png"));
  int[][] pcx = new int[height][width];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      if (image.getRGB(j, i) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        pcx[i][j] = 1;
  return pcx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to build a `char[]` for the line, fill it with blank hearts, then fill the sides with white hearts, and calculate and fill the center with white hearts.

The result is very concise and fast code, but the center calculation might seem complex, when though it's a simple formula.

```java
public static void printHeart(int n) {
    printHeart(n, '\u2665', '\u2661');
}

public static void printHeart(int n, char black, char white) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return;
    int width = 5 * n - 2;
    char[] buf = new char[width];
    for (int i = 1 - n; i < (width + 1) / 2; i++) {
        int outer = Math.abs(i), center = 2 - n - 2 * i;
        Arrays.fill(buf, black);
        Arrays.fill(buf, 0, outer, white);
        Arrays.fill(buf, width - outer, width, white);
        if (center > 0)
            Arrays.fill(buf, (width - center) / 2, (width + center) / 2, white);
        System.out.println(buf);
    }
}
```

Notice how the code doesn't need separate sections for printing top and bottom halfs. This is a trick achieved by iterating `i` from negative to positive numbers, e.g. for `n=4`, `i` is iterated from `-3` to `+8`, both inclusive.

*Tests*

Since the font on my browser don't use hearts of equal width, the result is bad, so the following test uses regular characters.

```java
for (int n = 0; n <= 6; n++)
    printHeart(n, 'X', '.');
```

*Outputs*

```
X.X
.X.
```

```
.XX..XX.
XXXXXXXX
.XXXXXX.
..XXXX..
...XX...
```

```
..XXX...XXX..
.XXXXX.XXXXX.
XXXXXXXXXXXXX
.XXXXXXXXXXX.
..XXXXXXXXX..
...XXXXXXX...
....XXXXX....
.....XXX.....
......X......
```

```
...XXXX....XXXX...
..XXXXXX..XXXXXX..
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
...XXXXXXXXXXXX...
....XXXXXXXXXX....
.....XXXXXXXX.....
......XXXXXX......
.......XXXX.......
........XX........
```

```
....XXXXX.....XXXXX....
...XXXXXXX...XXXXXXX...
..XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX..
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
...XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
....XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....
.....XXXXXXXXXXXXX.....
......XXXXXXXXXXX......
.......XXXXXXXXX.......
........XXXXXXX........
.........XXXXX.........
..........XXX..........
...........X...........
```

```
.....XXXXXX......XXXXXX.....
....XXXXXXXX....XXXXXXXX....
...XXXXXXXXXX..XXXXXXXXXX...
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
..XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX..
...XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...
....XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX....
.....XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.....
......XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX......
.......XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.......
........XXXXXXXXXXXX........
.........XXXXXXXXXX.........
..........XXXXXXXX..........
...........XXXXXX...........
............XXXX............
.............XX.............
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVLBcoIwEL3zFXsjKFJ1pvaAdqbTSy89eelM6yFgkCgEJwk6TodvpxvACkrHaQ4kbN6@ffs2W3qgo2zPxHa9K0ue7jOpYYtBL9c88Qa@ZYUJVQpeY8mVTql6Y1RqBd8W4NrnQcJDUJpq3A4ZX0NKuSBLLbnYfK6Ayo1yGrBZUSaBcKFBwALGPm7zBcxwHw7bsIobKXRVjQgX7A8bP57t@B3Q8qQ0S70s116FTwRpIQqrh@ypARTWXy20wJXUtrIrVV/5dDZ7tM@nif1vchfCmEoIEhrumvMx5pq1i/IISOXU2Ol0L5nOpbj0awiPfK1jNPcRBujuCKaXa0OOMwnyCO8FO9aBKmHl346II2qCDMLH4xxIzTyEiQMPSAv8dmYmDWfBJKa@Ux17NFCEO9gXE3V0agiNLJTHu7N8kZKelBfxJCGo0a09ce6Axm5d0W1suwOvmxj95pjf/lRjeiP7@dr4Xmpy5q6zKpfci22daF/BnreMvDfPubCKsvwB)